# Self join using criteria Query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria

I would like to find the greatest n per group from a table.

```
SELECT a.* FROM YourTable a
 LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTable b
 ON a.id = b.id AND a.rev < b.rev 
WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

As some inputs are dynamic I relied on using criteria queries.
As Criteria Joins require mapping of the entities this operation requires mapping the entity within itself.

Here is the entity I'm relying upon

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "user_order_package_subscription_v1")
public class UserOrderPackageSubscriptionV1 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_order_package_subscription_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userOrderPackageSubscriptionId;

    @Column(name = "total_paid_amount", nullable = false)
    private Double totalPaidAmount;

    @Column(name = "purchase_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime purchaseDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="uam_id", referencedColumnName = "uam_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private UserOrderPackageSubscriptionV1 uopsv1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "uam_id", referencedColumnName = "uam_id")
    private StudentDetailsV1 studentDetail;

}
```

The column in which I want to perform the left join is uam_id but it is a foreign key that refers to another table studentDetails and hence I have written another mapping for it.

The join segment from the service is as follows

```
    Root<UserOrderPackageSubscriptionV1> userOrderSubscriptionTableLeft = query.from(UserOrderPackageSubscriptionV1.class);

Join<UserOrderPackageSubscriptionV1, UserOrderPackageSubscriptionV1> selfJoin = userOrderSubscriptionTableLeft.join(UserOrderPackageSubscriptionV1_.uopsv1, JoinType.LEFT);
        selfJoin.on(
                       cb.lessThan(userOrderSubscriptionTableLeft.get("purchaseDate"),
                        selfJoin.get("purchaseDate"))
        );
```

But this makes the UAM_ID unique and tries to create a foreign key constraint on uam_id that self references the table.

Also if I remove referencedColumnName it joins using the uam_id and the user_order_package_subscription_id(PK of the table). How do I perform a self join.

Comment: "tries to create a foreign key constraint on uam_id" - The mapping itself is a separate feature from DDL. You can always use a script and customize it as you require. A uam_id -> uam_Id reference is not going to resolve into a single UserOrderPackageSubscriptionV1  instance. *ToOne foreign keys are required by JPA to be on the ID, to allow caching, but also because the referenced entity needs to be uniquely identified. You instead have something that is likely a collection mapping (OneToMany?) but even that doesn't seem right

Comment: The uopsv1 reference seems forced when you already have the relationship mapped with the studentDetail (it should have a OneToMany to UserOrderPackageSubscriptionV1). If you want to make querying easier, map the uam_id as a basic mapping - you can use UserOrderPackageSubscriptionV1 as a second root for your query and join over the basic mappings, or just use the studentDetail mapping. UserOrderPackageSubscriptionV1 sub1, UserOrderPackageSubscriptionV1  sub2 join on sub2.studentDetail = sub1.studentDetail.. ".